# Como se llama este menu?

Tags: android

Tengo este codigo (que no me marca errores):

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    menu.setHeaderTitle("En el parcial 2:");
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tienescero, menu);


}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cero:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Opcion 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.vacio:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Opcion 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Solamente quiero llamar ese menú, osea al presionar un botón verificar si un numero es igual a 0, si el numero es cero mostrar el menú.
Ya se hacer la condición con un if, pero no se como llamo a ese menú, como hago que se muestre?

```
if(numero ==  0){



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de Android, un menú contextual es:

> Un menú contextual ofrece acciones que afectan un elemento o marco contextual específicos en la IU. Puedes proporcionar un menú contextual para cualquier vista, aunque estos se usan con mayor frecuencia para elementos en ListView, GridView u otras colecciones de vistas en las cuales el usuario puede realizar acciones directamente en cada elemento.

En pocas palabras, un menú contextual es un menú que se abre en la posición de una vista al es decir; al momento de hacer click sobre una vista deberías poder visualizar un pequeño menú, junto a esta vista.

Una imagen dice mas que mil palabras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero bueno tal como dice la documentación es recomendable usar estos tipos de menu solo para elementos de una lista.

Para crear dichos menús puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

1. Añades un listener sobre la vista en la que quieres mostrar tu popup menu.
2. Creas un menu en el contexto de la vista y con la vista (recibida del metodo onClick)
3. Inflas el recurso menú que quieres mostrar.
4. Añades listeners al menu para controlar los clicks en sus opciones.
5. Muestras el menú.

   ```
           itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               //Creas el menu con la vista dada en el click listener.
               //Necesitas un contexto, lo puedes sacar de la misma vista
               PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
               //Inflas el menu que quieres mostrar.
               popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cliente_menu_ejecucion, popup.getMenu());

               //Añades listeners para recibir los clicks de las opciones del menu
               popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                       //Tras cada click de tu menu contextual recibiras dicha llamada aqui
                       return false;
                   }
               });
                //NO OLVIDES mostrar tu menu.
                 popup.show();
               }
         });
   ```